# Shared folder not accessible for app in monorepo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

In my project I have to store app and backend inside single repository. And now I have a problem because i need to create `shared` folder where i have to place every types needed in app and also in backend folder.

So I create shared folder and this is my project structure:

```
- project
-- app
--- tsconfig.json
--- package.json
-- shared
--- enums
--- interfaces
--- index.ts //exported enums and interfaces
-- backend
--- tsconfig.json
```

and this is my tsconfig.json inside app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "incremental": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "rootDirs": ["./src", "../shared"],
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["../shared/*"]
    }
  }
  // "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  // "include": ["src/**/*", "../shared/*"]
}
```

can someone tell me why when I import something from shared like here:

```
import { AccountRole } from "@shared/index";
```

then tsc compiler throw me in console this:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 20:0-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@shared/index' in 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\...\...\app\src'resolve '@shared/index' in 'C:\Users\...\Desktop\...\...\app\src
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file? you probably need to add a workspaces section to the file

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create a monorepo setup here, you need to have a package.json in shared as well and defined a name, and that name you can simply use in other two packages (app, backend). There has to be a root package.json which will a workspaces key for these packages. 
Check this understand in detail https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces